# Are there alternatives to String.format that use cached formatting?

Tags: java, formatting

Are there any alternatives to Java's String.format which can cache the format String insead of requiring a format parse on each run? it would probably look something like this

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter( "oh %s" );

formatter.format("my"); // oh my
```

Comment: Are you having a performance problem?

Comment: I've implemented a similar Formatter once, and I can assure you that format parsing is very low on the list of your worries when you format according to this paradigm.

Comment: @JuanMendes no I'm not, this is more of a coding style thought, including the lack of desire to reference strings all over the place. I thought I'd check to see if it was my only option for writing simple templated strings since my google foo didn't see anything like an Apache String format

Comment: @xenoterracide To fix the string problem, just make constants from them. Premature optimization is the root of a lot of evil

Comment: @JuanMendes premature optimization would be writing my own, this is really no different from asking about alternatives to the DateFormat, which actually do exist.

Comment: @JuanMendes also people often write premature optimization is ... without even understanding what actually constitutes premature optimization. They also use it to justify writing bad code and never thinking about optimization at all. I've had to fix much code recently because of this.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`MessageFormat` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

```
MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat("oh {0}");
System.out.println(mf.format(new Object[] {"my"}));
System.out.println(mf.format(new Object[] {"this will do it!"}));
```

Output:

```
oh my
oh this will do it!
```

Answer (score 5):

You could look into [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) you can create one instance for a pattern and use it like this:

```
MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(pattern); // initialize once
messageFormat.format(arguments, new StringBuffer(), null).toString(); // use often
```